# Disabling Auto duplex on a Pixma MG5220

Tags: printer, canon-pixma

I'm about to buy a Canon Pixma mg5220. One of its features is Auto Duplex Printing. Can this feature be disabled? Though normally I prefer printing double sided, there are times when I need to print documents in a a paper wasting fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an option selected at time of printing.  It is not "on" by default